# Jump Process - Random Walk

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, random-walk

> A 1-D random walker strarting at time $t=0$ and location $x=0$, moves to the right ($x+1$) or the left ($x-1$) according to **independent** random variables $R_1,R_2,\ldots$ and $L_1,L_2,\ldots$, such that the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ jump to the right occurs at the time $\sum_{i=1}^{k} R_i$ and the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ jump to the left occurs at the time $\sum_{i=1}^{k} L_i$. Assume $R_i$s and $L_i$s are samples of the same probability density function $f(x)$. Show that the probability that the location of the random walker remains $x\leq M$ after the first $N$ steps to the right, tends to $1-\delta$, for all $\delta>0$, as $N, M \to\infty$, as long as $M=\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$.

**My Solution**: If $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, the memorylessness of exponential random variables makes this problem equivalent to a symmetric random walk, then we can find the survival probability of a random walk and use the Brownian motion limit to prove this (see Survival Probability in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-hitting-time_model)). How about the general $f(x)$?

I think we make it equivalent to another Brownian motion, I don't know how to find the parameters of that Brownian motion.

Comment: I don't understand the role of $f_a/f_p$. Is this determining jump times or jump direction?

Comment: @Ian I edited the problem to clarify this. $f_r$ gives the jump time to right and $f_l$ gives the jump time to left.

Comment: Use jump probabilities instead of jump *time* probabilities.

Comment: @Therkel How? the jump probabilities change with time here.

Comment: Yes, if you are interested in step counts then you are really interested in the so-called "jump process" of the continuous time process, not the continuous time process itself. In the non-Markov case these are nontrivial to compute, but you still need them. (Presumably here you mean to have the arguments of the jump time densities be $t$ or $x,t$, not just $x$.)

Comment: @Ian Correct, I need the jump process. Jump probabilities are functions of $t$, and they depend on $x$ as well.

Comment: The jump time distribution depends on how long you have waited or also on the time you arrived in the first place? The latter would be rather weird for this context. In the former case the jump probabilities only depend on $x$ so that the jump process is Markov.

Comment: @Ian   Sorry again, I edited the problem to clarify this.

Comment: So what you want is the general case where the jump process is not necessarily Lévy? I think that is an interesting question!

Comment: The interesting thing here is that there is some "recurrence" structure built into the jump times; the system remembers not just where it is or even what it last did but even how long it has been since the last jump in each direction. This is a very long-term memory behavior which won't be manageable by standard renewal theory. On the other hand it seems like it might be tractable because you're just looking at a position of $\max \{ k : \sum_{i=1}^k R_i \leq t \} - \max \{ k : \sum_{i=1}^k L_i \leq t \}$.

Comment: @Ian right! It has a long memory!

Comment: @Therkel I have made some little changes to simplify it! Please see them.

Comment: @Ian I have made some little changes to simplify it! Please see them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66808/discussion-between-su20200-and-ian).

Comment: @Ian Thanks. Can you please explain more how you came up with the double integral?

Comment: Sorry, I made an error that is nontrivial to fix. I'll have to come back at this to some point.

Comment: @Ian It is now on bounty!

Comment: Let $X(t)$ denote this process, with $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \cdot 1_{\{x>0\}}$. It seems like you are claiming that $P(X(R_n) \leq \sqrt n)$ should converge to $1$ as $n \to \infty$. I do not believe that this is true. By CLT together with basic properties of the Poisson process, you can prove that $\frac{X(R_n)}{2\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$, therefore the probability $P(X(R_n) \leq \sqrt n)$ should tend to a number strictly less than $1$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @Shalop Thank you for your comment. Good point. I edited the last sentence of the problem statement. I should not say it goes to $1$. I have to say it can be as close as desired to $1$, i.e., for any $\delta$, it goes to $1-\delta$.

Comment: Hold your horses. It can't converge to $1-\delta$, for *all* $\delta>0$. Maybe you mean *some* $\delta>0$?. Or maybe you meant to choose a rate faster than $\sqrt N$, in which case it would converge to $1$? Hard to see what exactly you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Shalop's comments, in particular, we need $M$ to grow *faster* than $\sqrt{n}$ to get a probability that converges to 1.   Here is an analysis of the general problem.

Assume that $\{R_1, L_1, R_2, L_2, ...\}$ are i.i.d. positive random variables with mean $E[L]$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Assume $0<E[L]<\infty$, $0<\sigma^2<\infty$.  Let $X(t)$ be the (integer) location at time $t \geq 0$, with initial condition $X(0)=0$. Define
\begin{align}
t^R_n &= R_1 + R_2 + … + R_n\\
t^L_n &= L_1 + L_2 + … + L_n\\
N^R(t) &= \mbox{Number of right arrivals during $[0,t]$} \\
N^L(t) &= \mbox{Number of right arrivals during $[0,t]$} 
\end{align}
Then $X(t) = N^R(t) - N^L(t)$ for all $t \geq 0$ and 
$$ \boxed{X(t^R_n) = n - N^L(t^R_n)} \quad (Eq. *) $$
Now let $\{M_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be any sequence of non-negative integers that satisfies
\begin{align}
&n-M_n \geq 1 \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}\\
&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{M_n}{\sqrt{n}} = c \in [0, \infty)
\end{align}
We want to show that 
$$ \boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[X(t^R_n) > M_n] = \int_{\frac{cE[L]}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2}}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx}$$
We will use the fact that for all $t \geq 0$ and all positive integers $k$ we have
$$ \boxed{P[N^L(t)<k] = P[L_1 + … + L_k > t]}  \quad (Eq. **) $$

---

Define for each $i \in \{1, 2, 3, …\}$ 
\begin{align}
G_i &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\sum_{j=1}^i (L_i-E[L])\\
H_i &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\sum_{j=1}^i (R_i - E[L])
\end{align}
Then $\{G_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{H_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are independent, and the central limit theorem tells us that $G_i$ and $H_i$ both converge in distribution to a Gaussian with 0 mean and variance $\sigma^2$. We have
\begin{align}
P[X(t^R_n)>M_n] &\overset{(a)}{=} P[n-N^L(t^R_n) > M_n] \\
&= P[N^L(t^R_n) < n-M_n] \\
&\overset{(b)}{=} P[L_1 + … +L_{n-M_n} >t^R_n]\\
&\overset{(c)}{=} P[L_1 + … + L_{n-M_n} > R_1 + … + R_n] \\
&\overset{(d)}{=}P\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n-M_n}(L_i-E[L]) > M_nE[L] + \sum_{j=1}^n (R_i-E[L])\right]\\
&\overset{(e)}{=} P\left[G_{n-M_n} > \frac{M_nE[L]}{\sqrt{n-M_n}} + \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n-M_n}}\right)H_n  \right]
\end{align}
where (a) holds by  (Eq *); (b) holds by (Eq **) with $t=t^R_n$ and $k=n-M_n$; (c) holds by definition of $t^R_n$; (d) holds by subtracting $(n-M_n)E[L]$ from both sides of the inequality inside the $P[\cdot]$; (e) holds by dividing both sides of the inequality inside the $P[\cdot]$ by $\sqrt{n-M_n}$ and using definitions of $H_i$ and $G_i$.  Define 
$$ W_n = G_{n-M_n} - \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n-M_n}}\right)H_n$$
Then
$$ P[X(t^R_n)>M_n] = P\left[W_n > \frac{M_nE[L]}{\sqrt{n-M_n}}\right]$$
Note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{M_n}{\sqrt{n}} = c \in [0, \infty)$ implies the following: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n-M_n}} = 1 \quad ,\quad  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{M_nE[L]}{\sqrt{n-M_n}} = cE[L] \quad, \quad \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (n-M_n) = \infty$$
Since $G_{n-M_n}$ and $H_n$ are independent and individually converge in distribution to a Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$,  we know that  $W_n$ converges in distribution to a Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $2\sigma^2$. Hence
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[X(t^R_n)>M_n] = P[W > cE[L]]$$
where $W$ is Gaussian with mean 0 and variance $2\sigma^2$. $\Box$

Comment: On the other hand, if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{M_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \infty$, then similar methods can be used to show that $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[X(t^R_n)>M_n] = 0$$

Comment: Thank you! But, you are calculating the probability that the location of the random walker at the $n-th$ move to the right eventually becomes larger than $M_n$. I want something else. In my original proble, I want to show that the location has remained all the time less than $M$, from time zero to the time of the N-th move to the right., not eventually.

Comment: That aspect was not clear in the wording.  Nevertheless my answer indeed proves the thing you are trying to prove is false: The probability that we remain less than $M_n$ for all steps from 1...n is less than or equal to the probability that the $n$th step is less than $M_n$, which we know from the above answer does not go to 1.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please see Theorem 12.2 in "Stopped random walks"  by Allan Gut. When the distributions of $L_i$ and $R_i$ are exponential, it becomes a normal random walk, and Theorem 12.2 says what I need for this case. Therefore, I don't think your proof is correct.

Comment: I do not have access to that book.  I suspect that you are misinterpreting a result given there.  I observe that your use of $\delta$ in your question is awkward and that wording is unlikely to be in any book.  That is because if $p$ is a probability that is greater than $1-\delta$ for all $\delta>0$, then $p=1$ and there is no need to mention $\delta$. Note that Shalop pointed out the same issue.

Comment: I gave you the bounty. Let's discuss this later once I will provide more details to you, without referring to the book.

Comment: I pulled up that book online: The Theorem 12.2 stated there does not contradict my answer above.  If I am interpreting the notation in that theorem correctly, it is saying that the $n$th "local max" of a random walk, divided by $\sqrt{n}$, converges in distribution to a Gaussian.

Comment: That is right, and what I needed was the same thing for arbitrary distributions of $L_i$ and $R_i$.

Comment: The description in your question does not appear to be the same. I think my answer above is a good one for what was asked. It makes sense to move on, if you want to ask a different question it may be best to decouple it from this question.  Note that the $n$th step to the right is not the same as the $n$th local max.

Comment: Please see this problem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372038/survival-probability-random-walk-with-renewal-timings